# AQXMLParser error: property attributes 'assign' and 'weak' are mutually exclusive

Tags: iphone, ios

I am currently trying to add aqxmlparser to my ios project and have done everything in the github directory that they have explain to do however I am getting the error listed above.

```
property attributes 'assign' and 'weak' are mutually exclusive
```

and this is where the errors are happening

.h

```
 //..

        id<AQXMLParserProgressDelegate> __weak  _progressDelegate;
    //..

        @property (nonatomic, assign) id __weak delegate;
        @property (nonatomic, assign) id<AQXMLParserProgressDelegate> __weak progressDelegate;
    //..
```

Comment: Did you end up fixing this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Oh I see the original ones from AQToolkit are coded differently.

Comment: @huggie Did you remove the __weak declarations for these properties? The ones in the AQToolkit git repository are coded exactly as in the question above. Please inform what repository you are using?